# What is the difference between Oauth2 in angular (client-side) and in the node.js (server-side)? and when to implement each one?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, angular8

Due to the lack examples of **oauth2** in **node.js**, I can't decide where to implement the **oauth2** service. Also, I wanna know what is the meaning of **provider** in **oauth2** and when to create a new one and when to use a pre-made one like google.

I tried to implement a **provider** in the **server-side** but I didn't know how to test it.

If there are any useful resources I would be happy to take them.

Comment: Well, googling for `oauth2 node.js server example` returns at least few useful links. There's even the `oauth2-server` package at npm. Are you sure you lack examples?

Comment: I found the package at npm , but as I said there is a lack of examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Open Id Connect (Authorization Code Flow + PKCE) in your Angular app. You should validate OAuth 2.0 access tokens in your API. Both of these components should interact with a 3rd party Authorization Server. There is a learning curve and my tutorial + code sample may help you - feel free to post back if you get stuck: https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/

Comment: How can I implement the Authorization Server?

Answer (score 0):

oauth2 provider means wich service to use to auth, eg `server-side` will mean the user creates an account on your Server, `google` would mean users sign in with their google accoutns to your site.

Comment: Is it good to implement the oauth2 service on the client or on the server side ???